# Conflicts between document versions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

how to manage conflicts between document versions when saving in mongo database by working with mongoose in nestJS ?

I try to check if there are no conflicts between versions of a document before saving based on the __v property of mongoose documents. Here is my code

```
async miseAJourDoc(docToUpdate: MyClass) {
    const updatedDoc = await this.docModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: docToUpdate._id, __v: docToUpdate.__v },
        { ...docToUpdate, $inc: { __v: 1 } },
        { new: true },
    ).exec();
    if (!updatedDoc) {
        // Gérer le cas où la version actuelle du document ne correspond pas à celle récupérée précédemment
        throw new ConflictException('La version du document a été modifiée par un autre utilisateur.');
    }
    return updatedDoc;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Does your code not work?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, but no my code does not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in my post. What I want is to be able to manage possible version problems when updating a document. That is to say if two users do the same action on a resource at the same time by modifying different fields that I can manage it without losing all the modifications